# Download current page HTML with out creating a new session

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest, forms-authentication

I have a webpage which is windows forms authenticated ,and i want to download a copy of this page's HTML in to my server, when user request this page. I have tried something like this

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            string htmlCode = client.DownloadString("http://aksphases:200/lynliste.aspx");  
        }
```

which doesn't gives me correct result because of the URL I had passes to system creates new session.And in that case i need to authenticate this web-request,which I can't do.Only way to authenticate this webpage is that user log in manually(I know ways to authenticate werequests by code,but I can't try that here for some special reasons). Is there any  other way for me to download current page's HTML which is running in in browser with out authenticating the URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could send the current forms authentication cookie along with the request:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Cookie] = 
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Cookie"];
    string htmlCode = client.DownloadString("http://aksphases:200/lynliste.aspx");  
}
```

This way we are basically transferring the current HTTP request cookies to the remote HTTP call.

Comment: ...with the caveat that this is passing ALL of the user's cookies to the 3rd party server, which might reflect a serious security hole...

Answer (score 0):

If the web server does not allow anonymous access then there is no way around - you must authenticate yourself with the web site.

However, contrary to your belief that log on operation has to be done manually, it can be done via code also. In case of windows authentication, pass credentials via [Credentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.credentials.aspx) property. For Forms authentication, you need to POST log-on credentials to login page and then use the authentication cookie from the response in subsequent request (Use tool such fiddler to inspect request/responses from browser to replicate same within your code).